# Запятая между сказуемыми разных типов

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сказуемые, однородные-члены

Ставится ли запятая в предложениях, где одно сказуемое выражено существительным, а другое глаголом?

> Иван — лучший боец среди них(,) и выполнит работу...

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите предложение полностью, чтобы содержание  и грамматика были  понятны.

Comment: Для связности речи здесь требуется местоимение "он" (и **он** выполнит работу); запятая при этом нужна.

Answer (score 3):

**Иван — лучший боец среди них и выполнит работу...**
Запятая перед "и" не нужна, потому что союз соединяет **однородные** сказуемые (они относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему ("Иван")).

В учебнике Н. С. Валгиной "Синтаксис современного русского языка" подобные предложения приведены в качестве примера ([Однородные главные члены предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm)):

> К предложениям переходного типа относятся и предложения с разнооформленными сказуемыми: *Она молода, изящна, любит жизнь* (Ч.); *Я бродяга и страстно люблю жизнь* (Пауст.); *Вы — доктор и отлично знаете, что вам вреден сырой воздух* (Ч.).

Я "много порылась" и нашла похожие предложения у классиков.

> Ежели ты идешь на дуэль и пишешь завещания да нежные письма родителям, ежели ты думаешь о том, что тебя могут убить, **ты — дурак и наверно пропал**...
> [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир](https://ilibrary.ru/text/11/p.69/index.html)

> Я думал, ты и вправду умный человек, а **ты — идиот и книжки читаешь идиотские**!
> [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Цусима](https://books.google.ee/books?id=denJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT213&lpg=PT213&dq=%E2%80%95%20%D0%AF%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB,%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA,%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5!&source=bl&ots=e4Dl15MmLn&sig=ACfU3U0xVQugLia1DPyDpzQDL-t5yJUf3Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2gI7KmcXxAhUmmIsKHSXYDjYQ6AEwDXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%95%20%D0%AF%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5!&f=false)

**Ещё предложения** (*А есть ли у классиков примеры без местоимений?*)

Ещё порылась:
Но **человек существо легкомысленное и неблаговидное и**, может быть, подобно шахматному игроку, **любит** только один процесс достижения цели, а не самую цель. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Записки из подполья (1864)]
― Но позволь, ― сказал он, ― если предложить осужденному на выбор смертную казнь сегодня или завтра, то он всегда выберет завтра, так как **человек ― существо в высшей степени легковерное и** до последней минуты **надеется** на какое-то чудодейственное избавление. [А. Н. Будищев. В неприятной компании (1897)]
**Человек ― существо нормальное и не может жить**, отрицая жизнь. [А. И. Батюто. Дневник (1947)]

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь мы точно знаем, что для связности речи здесь не требуется местоимение "он".

Comment: Здесь всё-таки лучше с запятой и "он", потому что именное сказуемое должно быть кратким, как у классиков, чтоб предложение звучало. Без запятой здесь звучит не по-русски, но так теоретически допустимо. Так что в "связности речи" всё-таки есть смысл. А есть ли у классиков примеры без местоимений? Они, опять же, способствуют краткости, и пауза тире меньше, или вообще тире нет.

Comment: _...именное сказуемое должно быть кратким..._ Возможно. Но посмотрите ещё примеры — мне кажется, что всё здесь звучит по-русски.

Comment: "он" нужен при перевороте:
"Я люблю жизнь и бродяга"

Comment: "Он" очень желательно в примере из вопроса, тем более что там есть следствие (которое принято пунктуационно отображать). В примере Достоевского вводное и сравнение смягчают переход и звучит. В третьем — есть краткость. А во втором так странновато (несуразно) звучит, как и в примере из вопроса.

Comment: Но пример №2 лучше звучит, чем пример из вопроса, из-за наличия следствия и будущего времени в последнем. Могу сказать, что настоящее время способствует  такой конфигурации, так как оно выступает общим для сказуемых и как бы соединяет их (в случае именного можно подставить глагол "есть").