# Нужна ли запятая между глаголами разных времён?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сказуемые, однородные-члены, и

«Мы следим за всеми изменениями и будем держать вас в курсе событий»

*Следим* и *будем* — глаголы разных времён. Могут ли они быть однородными членами или между ними всё-таки должна стоять запятая, так как это сложное предложение?

Answer (score 1):

**Мы следим за всеми изменениями и будем держать вас в курсе событий.**

Запятая перед союзом "и" не нужна, потому что он соединяет **однородные сказуемые**, относящиеся к одному и тому же подлежащему ("мы").
Обычно однородные члены предложения отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, но со сказуемыми это правило не работает.
Однородные сказуемые могут быть представлены и глаголами разного времени, и глаголами разного вида; иногда одно сказуемое может быть именным, а другое — глагольным.
*Вы — доктор **и** отлично знаете, что вам вреден сырой воздух* (Чехов).
*Я бродяга **и** страстно люблю жизнь* (Паустовский).

Вот похожие предложения.
***Мы следим** за ситуацией **и будем заниматься** решением вопросов по мере их поступления* (газета "Ärileht"); ***Мы следим** за рыночной конъюнктурой **и будем** оперативно **реагировать** на изменение стоимости ресурсов* (ТАСС).

> **Мы следим и будем** и впредь **следить** за этим процессом, и будем единственными, кто станет руководить этим и принимать соответствующие решения.
> М. Гилберт. Черчилль и евреи

[Однородные главные члены предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm)

Дополнение
При цитировании после закрывающих кавычек необходима точка.
Второе сказуемое в предложении — *будем держать*.

Comment: "*Вы — доктор и отлично знаете*" — был такой вопрос, думал, что такое объединение сказуемых не используется. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464620

Comment: Этот вопрос мне на глаза не попадался (скорее всего, был успокоительный период). Теперь же я на него ответила. Будет желание — гляньте.